# Easyadmin An error has occurred resolving the options of the form. Invalid upload directory it does not exist or is not writable

Tags: symfony, debian, easyadmin, symfony6

I've made an application for my exams using symfony 6, Easyadmin4 and debian10 for my dedicated server.

I create in EasyAdmin, an Header feature to change my header from my EasyAdmin menu.

There is the code for my ProductCrudController.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Product;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\SlugField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\ImageField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\MoneyField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\BooleanField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextareaField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\AssociationField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;

class ProductCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
{
    return Product::class;
}


public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
    
    return [
        TextField::new('name'),
        SlugField::new('slug')
        ->setTargetFieldName('name'),
        ImageField::new('illustration')
        ->setBasePath('uploads')
        ->setUploadDir('public/uploads')
        ->setUploadedFileNamePattern('[randomhash].[extension]')
        ->setRequired(false),
        TextField::new('subtitle'),
        TextareaField::new('description'),
        BooleanField::new('isBest'),
        MoneyField::new('price')
        ->setCurrency('EUR'),
        AssociationField::new('category')
    ];
    
    
    
    /* return [
        IdField::new('id'),
        TextField::new('title'),
        TextEditorField::new('description'),
    ]; */
}

}
```

I store my uploads in `myappanme/public/uploads`
Everything works fine using my local server Mamp, but online it's not working.

I have this error :

```
An error has occurred resolving the options of the form 
"EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Form\Type\FileUploadType": Invalid upload directory 
"/var/www/sodelicious/public/uploads/" it does not exist or is not writable.
```

My uploads folder `/var/www/sodelicious/public/uploads` is there. I don't understand why i have this symfony error.

I've tried to change the syntax of my `->setUploadDir` but the error persists.

If anybody can tell me what i am doing wrong it would be nice, thanks

Comment: have you set the right permission on your server for the "uploads" folder?

Comment: hm nope. I have to use the chmod command for this directory ? or is it in the VirtualHost configuration ? (that's my first app, i don't get everything at the first time sorry )

Comment: As the error highlight, this could be a permission issue so you need to check if that folder have the right permission, and yes you can use a chmod command from your control panel to set it.

Comment: It s good now . 
Effectively, this folder was not rewritable..  i use chmod to change the permission and it s working now . Thanks